# Database table design, user menu strip access, winforms

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, winforms, database-design

I have a requirement on a Winforms desktop app that the options on the fileMenStrip are hidden / displayed depending on the user access rights. Roles cannot be used as different access is given on a person by person basis.

I'm trying to figure out the database design for the requirement.

Currently I have a userTable, fileMenuTableLevel1, fileMenuTableLevel2, with bridging tables.

I know this is not right but I'm not sure how to represent that level 2 is a submenu item of level 1.

Also if there needs to be a third level then a new table must be created.

I have an idea of having one table to represent the access with the 'parentId' simply another column on the table referencing the menuId. this doesnt feel right either though as I can't figure out where to store if it's visible or not.

What is the best way of representing this?

[Design that I know is incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2XUp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the following which allows for an **arbitrary** number of child elements to be added to the parent.
Use a **self referencing key** (either explicitly declared with a constraint or without one).

**MENU_ELEMENTS_TABLE**

:ID

:ELEMENT_TYPE

:PARENT_ID

...

Note: The top most element (ie. the first parent will have a PARENT_ID of null or the default value or a value that is then common for all top level parents to be able to distinguish it from child elements. Deleting an entry can be added by a Cascading Delete constraint.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an idea of having one table to represent the access with the 'parentId' simply another column on the table referencing the menuId. this doesnt feel right either though as i cant figure out where to store if its visible or not.

You have the right idea trying to store all of the file menu elements in one table. I'm not sure I understand your 'visbility' problem. Its seems to me if your schema consisted of these three tables:

User

MenuElement

UserMenuElement

Then visibility would simply be stored on the UserMenuElement linking table. I would argue the field may be irrelevant though, the presence of an entry should indicate that you do have access.

Comment: Yeah that does make more sense actually. The 'visible' column, and where to store it, was the issue stopping me from using the one table for the MenuElements, but as you said, it is irrelevant and removing that column fixes everything. Thanks for the help!